# Use raw json in Command attribute (/setblock)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

So, I'm making a machine in a minecraft server that detects if someone is holding a cake named Flying Cake and then make them be able to fly. It was working perfectly, until I realized plugin's commands can't use selectors. This is a problem because the /fly command cannot detect which player to toggle flight.

So far I have this command: `execute if entity @a[distance=..10,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:cake",tag:{display:{Name:"\"Flying Cake\""}}}}]`

And this one: `setblock ~2 ~ ~ command_block{Command:""}`

What I'm trying to do is make the second command block set the next command block to /fly (player) enable. To do that, you need to get raw JSON in the {Command:""}. I will be using: `[{"text":"fly "},{"selector":"@a[distance=..10,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:cake",tag:{display:{Name:"\"Flying Cake\""}}}}]"},{"text":" enable"}]`

Is this possible?

Comment: What plugin are you using to grant flight?

Comment: I am using Essentials

Comment: Does `/execute as @a[distance=..10,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:cake",tag:{display:{Name:"\"Flying Cake\""}}}}] run fly @s enable` work? Or maybe without `@s` if it defaults to the executing player. It may be obvious to you that it can't work if it doesn't, but I don't know much about plugins and I think it's worth trying in case it does work. (Though I'm assuming that you probably tried something like this already)

Comment: The solution is obvious: Poke the plugin developer with a stick until they implement proper player selectors. :D

Comment: @RowdyRhino87 Your question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate, you are using selectors and you are on a spigot server with plugins. I have a working answer to your problem (using plugins) that I can post when the "marked as duplicate" is removed. If you edit your question and then flag it for moderators you should be able to get the "marked as duplicate removed." For the sake of you being able to fix this sooner than later, here is your solution: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/commandhook.61415/